# Optimum way to populate data in RecyclerView item at runtime

Tags: android, view, adapter, android-recyclerview

I am having a recycler view in which I populate a item and in each item certain elements are fixed but there is also some details which are populated on runtime, I mean for some item there can be 3 detailed view for some 10 and for some 2. 
As views in the item are created at runtime the recyclerview scrolling has became slow and jerk is observed.

Currently I am using a `LinearLayout` container in which i populate items using `container#addView(view)`

Please suggest any optimum way to do the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using that only but in adapter when data needs to be populated it is changing on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to set up item view types.

First, you create multiple layout XML files.  Maybe you have one with a single detail view, one with 2 detail views, one with 3, one with 4, etc.  There may be too many variations to get an XML layout for each one, but can you cover  80%-90% of them?  Having specific layouts for your most common cases will improve your performance quite a bit.

Then in your adapter, you override `getItemViewType(int position)` to return a specific int value for each view type you have.  So let's say your layout with 3 detail views is `viewType == 3` (conveniently).  When this is called with position 10, you look at your data at position 10.  If it needs 3 detail views, you return a viewType of 3.

Now, when your `onCreateViewHolder` method is called, you will have a `viewType` parameter to tell you which view to inflate.  You can have a `switch` statement that inflates specific XML layouts based on the view type ID.

How does this help?  Because the `RecyclerView` tracks your view types, and by having each layout identified by a specific view type, the `RecyclerView` knows to recycle a view *of that view type* when you need a new view.  So if you need a view with 3 detail views, the `RecyclerView` has them filed under `viewType == 3` and will give you a `ViewHolder` ready for your data.

Give it a try.  You should see a visible boost in performance.

Comment: Thank you kris, will definately try this.